# How to make Python choose the greatest number from 5 inputs(simple)way?

Tags: python, input, range

The problem is:
we write down a code

```
x = int(input("enter the number here"))
```

then we loop that 5 times with range and we want python to tell us which number is the greatest of all for example

## 1,10,100,1000

the greatest number is 1000
how can we do that?

I just do not know how to do it

Comment: Just build a list and pass it to `max`? You can also just update the largest value seen so far immediately after reading an input; after you are done collecting your input, you'll have the largest value.

Comment: Your question is super vague, like "what do I do?", which depends on where exactly you're stuck. Some puzzle pieces to help: "loop" -> `for`/`in`, `range()`. "greatest number" -> `max()`, "five numbers" -> `list`. Try putting something together, and when you get stuck, show where you're at and ask a concrete question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's exactly what you want but here is an input combined with a for loop in a range :

```
answers = []
for i in range(5):
    x = int(input("enter the number here : "))
    answers.append(x)


greatest_number = max(answers)
print("The greatest number is {}".format(greatest_number))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy approach:

```
nums = (input().split(','))
print(max(list(map(int, nums))))
```

As the input is taken as a string, when converting it to a list, the elements will be strings. The function `map` will convert each string in the list to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by splitting the input with respect to `","`. After splitting the str should be turn into `int` using for loop. Now use `max` function with the new integer list to get the maximum number.
so your final code should be:

```
x = input("enter the number here: ")
list = x.split(",")

int_list = []

for s in list:
    int_list.append(int(s))

max_num = max(int_list)
```